# WiFi not working - wlan0 FAILED

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, kernel-modules, laptop

My Arch (`3.6.5-1`) is exhibiting a rather peculiar problem: when wifi is set up, all logs indicate that the setup was successful and that the interface is up and functional. However, when attempting to access a website (or execute ping) all requests time out (despite that connection is reported as working and signal at 63% strength). This tends to happen randomly after laptop is switched on - after some time the connection usually starts working and does not break until next shutdown/suspend.

Relevant `dmesg` entries (full `dmesg` output can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/PH7jb8fy)):

```
[   13.858528] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   14.024275] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link down
[   14.024339] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   34.895920] wlan0: authenticate with 00:24:6c:c8:e4:a1
[   34.900827] wlan0: send auth to 00:24:6c:c8:e4:a1 (try 1/3)
[   34.902963] wlan0: authenticated
[   34.908362] wlan0: associate with 00:24:6c:c8:e4:a1 (try 1/3)
[   34.911153] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:24:6c:c8:e4:a1 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=9)
[   34.911217] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   34.911294] wlan0: associated
```

`ip -s link` shows:

```
wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:b7:c3:1e:f4:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    14970982   50472    0       0       0       0      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    19116      233      0       0       0       0
```

`ip minotor` outputs some failure messages:

```
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[LINK]3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
    link/ether 
[LINK]3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN 
    link/ether 50:b7:c3:1e:f4:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[LINK]3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DORMANT 
    link/ether 50:b7:c3:1e:f4:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[LINK]3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
    link/ether 
[LINK]3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
    link/ether 
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[LINK]3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP 
    link/ether 50:b7:c3:1e:f4:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]ff02::2 dev wlan0 lladdr 33:33:00:00:00:02 NOARP
[NEIGH]ff02::1:ff1e:f421 dev wlan0 lladdr 33:33:ff:1e:f4:21 NOARP
[NEIGH]ff02::16 dev wlan0 lladdr 33:33:00:00:00:16 NOARP
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]144.32.79.218 dev lo lladdr 00:00:00:00:00:00 NOARP
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[LINK]3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
    link/ether 
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
[NEIGH]144.32.78.1 dev wlan0  FAILED
```

All that should be loaded seem to be ([output of lsmod](http://pastebin.com/zJm1NiX9)). Any idea on how to solve this or what the problem is?

Comment: Are you actually getting or configuring some IP address after associating? Even if you're associated to the wireless network, you still have to, for example, run a DHCP client.

Comment: @njsg: Yes, DHCP client was run (automatically) and acquired an IP address.

Comment: old question i know but i'm getting this as well. [i thought i had fixed this issue](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190754/wpa-supplicant-nightmares) but its coming back again now. so far i'm thinking it is failing hardware.

Answer (score 0):

-my recent experience with a plug in USB WiFi device might be relevant to this discussion.  I am using an older HP Compaq desktop computer, with Linux Mint operating system, and a plug in "WLAN 11g USB Adapter" that I bought maybe 10 years ago.  It worked OK for several years, but I have been having problems with lost internet connection, requiring me to shut down the computer, and come back an hour or so later to get back online.  I thought I was encountering some sort of software internet throttle, & did not realize this might be a hardware problem in my own computer.  A salesperson at Frye Electronics said he had heard of similar issues/problems with "WiFi cards," & he thought I should look into this. I knew the WiFi adapter got warm, & I knew it was an RF transceiver, which meant that it used significant power required to broadcast a signal.  To improve cooling, I removed the plastic case, & now I have a small exposed circuit board plugged into the back of my computer.  Since this modification was made, I have not seen any lost internet connections, at all.  The problem appears to have been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to change the current network manager:

```
systemctl status systemd-networkd
```

If it's enabled, you could try to disable it and enable NetworkManager (make sure it's installed), or vice-versa.

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl stop systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
sudo reboot
```